# Vuex ReferenceError is not defined. How do I set a value correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have an action in Vuex with a function **signUp()** how do I set a value for **signupError**?

This is what I have tried: `commit(signupError, null)` and `$state.commit(signupError, null)`  however I get an error "ReferenceError: signupError is not defined"

How do I set signupError in the following example?

store.js

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: null,
    signupError: null
  },


  actions: {
    async signUp({ commit }, { username, password, firstName, lastName }) {
      commit(signupError, null)
      try {
        const data = await Auth.signUp({
          username,
          password,
          attributes: {
            email: username
          }
        });
       
      } catch (error) {
        state.signupError = err.message || err
        console.log('error signing up:', error);
        return error;
    }
```

main.js

```
....

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store, // Vuex mechanism to "inject" the store into all child components from the root component.
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

reg.vue

```
....
 await this.$store.dispatch('signUp', {....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a mutation but a call to `commit` requires a mutation to commit.

```js
mutations: {
  SET_ERROR(state, value) {
    state.signupError = value;
  }
}
```

When you call `commit`, pass it the mutation name and the payload:

```js
commit('SET_ERROR', null);
```

You also need to use this in the `catch` block because you can't set `state` from an action:

```js
commit('SET_ERROR', error.message || error);
```

<sup>You used both `err` and `error`, make sure to keep it consistent</sup>

The whole action:

```js
actions: {
  async signUp({ commit }, { username, password, firstName, lastName }) {
    commit('SET_ERROR', null);
    try {
      const data = await Auth.signUp({
        username,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email: username
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      commit('SET_ERROR', error.message || error);
      console.log('error signing up:', error);
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you are not doing anything with the data from the async call.

Comment: So I managed to get it to work but in a different way and I'm not sure why it worked. On the function signUp I used async signUp { commit, state }... etc and then I can just do this `if (error) state.signupError = error.message || error;`

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but I didn't need to use a mutation this way, why?

Comment: If your store was in `strict` mode it would throw an error, it's not recommended.  You want to always use mutations to change state.  It works because it's indeed still the `state` object, the same one used in the mutation, but think of it as read-only in an action